# How to correctly handle Params and Querys in Axios?

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm consuming an **API with NODEJS** and using the **axios to do the "get"** ...

In **NODEJS** we call **"params"** everything that comes **before** the **"?"** Character, and we call the **"query"** everything that goes **after** the **"?"** Character, **such as:**

```
https://www.url.com/testing.xsjs?QueryName1='test1,test1'&QueryName2=1
```

**The problem** I'm having in Axios is that it **does not create the url correctly**, which the correct URL should be:

```
https: //www.url.comho/fatSales.xsjs?Shop='shop1,shop2,shop3'&PeriodoDe=201801&PeriodoAte=201807&Kpi='kp1,kp2,kp3'& Select = NUCOMPETEC
```

**But the url he is creating for me is this:**

```
https://www.apiUrl.com/Shop=shop1, + shop2, + shop3&PeriodoDe=201801&PeriodoAte=201807&Kpi=kp1,+kp2,+kp3&Select=NUCOMPETEC
```

**I have some issues with this URL that it creates that are as follows:**

**1)** Shop and Kpi it creates the "+" character
**2)** It does not add the parameter (NODEJS) before the "?" Character ...

**Remembering that:
Shop and Kpi (It's an array with 1 or * elements)**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const Qs    = require('qs');

class ApiDAO {
    constructor(xsjs, shoppingId, periodOf, periodUntil, kpi, select){
        this.xsjs        = xsjs;
        this.shoppingId  = shoppingId;
        this.periodOf    = periodOf;
        this.periodUntil = periodUntil;
        this.kpi         = kpi;
        this.select      = select;
    }

    configAxios(){
        return axios.create({
            method:              'GET',
            responseType:        'json',
            responseEncoding:    'utf8',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':  "application/json",
                'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
                Authorization:   "",
                Apikey:          "", 
            },
            params: {
                xsjs:       this.xsjs,
                Shop:       this.shoppingId,
                PeriodoDe:  this.periodOf,
                PeriodoAte: this.periodUntil,
                Kpi:        this.kpi,
                Select:     this.select
            },
        });
    }

    async getResponseAxios(){
        return await this.configAxios().get('https://www.apiUrl.com/');
    }
}

module.exports = () => { return ApiDAO };
```

Comment: What is `shoppingId`?

Comment: @Explosion PIlls 
mall identifier

Comment: No, I mean what is it literally like if you did `console.log`

Comment: @Explosion Pills 'BSC'

Comment: Then shouldn't the string have `Shop=BSC`?

Comment: No, because they did something in the external api that should receive as 'BSC'

Answer (score 0):

Are you stringifying your params? Can you try the following:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const Qs    = require('qs');

class ApiDAO {
    constructor(xsjs, shoppingId, periodOf, periodUntil, kpi, select){
        this.xsjs        = xsjs;
        this.shoppingId  = shoppingId;
        this.periodOf    = periodOf;
        this.periodUntil = periodUntil;
        this.kpi         = kpi;
        this.select      = select;
    }

configAxios(url){
    return axios.get({
        method:              'GET',
        url:                 url,
        responseType:        'json',
        responseEncoding:    'utf8',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':  "application/json",
            'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
            Authorization:   "",
            Apikey:          "", 
        },
        params: {
            xsjs:       this.xsjs,
            Shop:       this.shoppingId,
            PeriodoDe:  this.periodOf,
            PeriodoAte: this.periodUntil,
            Kpi:        this.kpi,
            Select:     this.select
        },
    });
}

async getResponseAxios(){
    return await this.configAxios('https://www.apiUrl.com/');
}
}

module.exports = () => { return ApiDAO };
```

Or if you want to use axios create, pass the URL in earlier as an option field. I don't think it's an error with the other params.

Comment: Also since you're requiring querystring, you might as well use it to sanitize your params. See the axios docs here, they have an example of your exact case using querystring: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios